# Angular 2: Inserting capture element dynamically when creating components (dynamically)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

My goal is to create a child component and insert into the parent component template. There are examples to do this. **However, I create parent component template (DOM Elements) dynamically in the parent component** while most of the examples shown statically create the template with the capture element.

Here's the code

app.component

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';
import {NewChildComponent} from "./newChild.component";

@Component({
 selector: 'app-main',
 templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

 @ViewChild('captureElement', {read: ViewContainerRef})
 captureElement: ViewContainerRef;

 constructor (private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
 var childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(NewChildComponent); 

 var myArea = document.getElementById('myArea');
 var myRow = document.createElement("div");
 myArea.appendChild(myRow);

 //I want to add the capture element #myCapture as a child of myRow
 //Add something like this <div #captureElement></div> programmatically through JS/TS
 // How can I do this?

 // I then create the component
  this.parent.createComponent(NewChildComponent);

 }
```

app.component.html

```
<div id="myArea">
  <!-- Static way of doing it -->
  <!--<div #captureElement></div>-->      
</div>
```

Instead of statically defining in `#captureElement` where the child component would be inserted, I would like to create it dynamically in the parent component and make it a child component.

Here are a list of questions I referred before I asked this question

- [Angular2: Insert a dynamic component as child of a container in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093727/angular2-insert-a-dynamic-component-as-child-of-a-container-in-the-dom)
- [How to place a dynamic component in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185820/how-to-place-a-dynamic-component-in-a-container?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Tried a couple of things

1. Tried to create a `div` element with a `#captureElement` as an
   attribute programmatically but that doesn't work.
2. Tried to create a random element programmatically and use `ViewContainerRef` to find it. That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 19):

We can't create a `ViewContainerRef`, as a `ViewContainerRef` only exists within a view.

In 2.3.0, `attachView` was introduced which allows you to be able to attach change detection to the ApplicationRef. You can create some class that will encapsulate your logic like:

```
export class HtmlContainer {
   private attached: boolean = false;

   private disposeFn: () => void;

   constructor(
    private hostElement: Element,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    private injector: Injector) {
  }

  attach(component: Type<any>) : ComponentRef<any> {
    if(this.attached) {
      throw new Error('component has already been attached')
    }

    this.attached = true;
    const childComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

    let componentRef = childComponentFactory.create(this.injector);

    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
    this.disposeFn = () => {
        this.appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
        componentRef.destroy();
    };

    this.hostElement.appendChild((componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0]);

    return componentRef;
  }

  dispose() {
    if(this.attached) {
      this.disposeFn();
    }
  }
}
```

this class is just helper that

1) resolves your dynamic component

```
this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
```

2) then compiles component by calling `compFactory.create`

3) after that registers its `changeDetector` (`componentRef.hostView` extends `ChangeDetectorRef`) by calling mentioned above `appRef.attachView` (otherwise change detection won't work for your component)

4) and finally appends the rootNode of your component to the host element

```
this.hostElement.appendChild((componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0]);
```

You can use it as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div id="myArea"></div> `,
  entryComponents: [NewChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  containers: HtmlContainer[] = [];

  constructor(
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var myArea = document.getElementById('myArea');
    var myRow = document.createElement("div");
    myArea.appendChild(myRow);

    this.addComponentToRow(NewChildComponent, myRow, 'test1');
    this.addComponentToRow(NewChildComponent, myRow, 'test2');
  }

  addComponentToRow(component: Type<any>, row: HTMLElement, param: string) {
    let container = new HtmlContainer(row, this.appRef, this.componentFactoryResolver, this.injector);
    let componentRef = container.attach(component);
    componentRef.instance.param1 = param;

    this.containers.push(container);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.containers.forEach(container => container.dispose());
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Py6UWEZRIeKRIRyFBiIL?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular2 - Component into dynamicaly created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element)
- [Angular2 Dynamic Component Injection in Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857222/angular2-dynamic-component-injection-in-root/40687392#40687392)
- https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.1/src/lib/core/portal/dom-portal-host.ts#L30-L86 (you can find here fallback for angular < 2.3.0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where is this `HtmlContainer` class going to sit? I mean .. which component?

Comment: I created `HtmlContainer` as a helper classes and it worked beautifully. Thanks again. Would it be possible for you to elaborate on what `HtmlContainer` class is doing?

Comment: Thanks. How can I maintain the dynamic components so that I can delete them? Tried maintaining an object which stored a reference to `componentRef.instance` in `addComponent` each time a new dynamic component was being created. Calling `.destroy()` on this didnt really work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @yurzui It seems that `dipose` method in `HtmlContainer` is not disposing the component. Instead the component is exactly where we inserted it any ideas why?