# Dynamic Components into already existing DOM elements

Tags: angular, angular-components

I can't figure out how to attach a dinamically created component to a DOM element created by an external JS library.

This is the code inside my root component:

```
markers.push(
    L.marker(
      [mapEvent.lng, mapEvent.lat],
      {
        icon: L.icon({
          iconUrl: mapEvent.iconURL,
          iconSize: [22, 22],
          iconAnchor: [11, 11] // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        })
      }
    ).bindPopup(
      L.popup(
        {
          closeButton: true
        }
      ).setContent(
        '<template #popupHost></template>'
      )
    )
  );
```

Essentially, this code is creating some elements inside the DOM that are not handled by me, and I want to use the setContent method to put my own code. What i would like to do is to inject a component inside this dynamically.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I've already read those solutions but nothing is working in my case... i'm blocked because when I try to call createComponent(factory) on the ViewContainerRef object (created by @ChildView), i get a 'Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined'

Comment: Please create plunker with your issue. I will have a look

Comment: MapComponent is using Leaflet to create a map and place some markers. Clicking on markers i want to see my own popup box, style and text, and also i want it to interact with the state of the map. This means that i can't use a static way to do this. https://plnkr.co/edit/czNxh4HmRMVp2HvfHrmM?p=catalogue

Comment: `I've already read those solutions but nothing is working in my case` i guess you didn't read these answers ) I'm working on your example

Comment: How do you build map? Do you use @asymmetrik/angular2-leaflet?

Comment: yes. i'm using it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without ViewContainerRef but you should have access to DOM element where you want to place your dynamic component.

First of all you need to create instance of your component like:

```typescipt
constructor(
  private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
  private inj: Injector) {}
...
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopupComponent);
this.componentRef = factory.create(this.inj);
```

then you need to configure your communication with this component:

```typescipt
export class PopupComponent {

  text: String;

  @Output() textChanged = new EventEmitter();  
}

this.componentRef.instance.text = popup.options.data;
this.subscription = this.componentRef.instance.textChanged.subscribe((val) => {
        this.data = val;
     });
```

after that you need to add component to the DOM

```typescipt
someDOMElement.appendChild((this.componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0]);
```

and finally make sure that your component is checked by angular change detection:

host.component.ts

```typescipt
ngDoCheck() {
   if(this.componentRef) {
     this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DA7fmiskbh0ypKNUmLxM?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular2 - Component into dynamicaly created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element)
- [Angular 2: Inserting capture element dynamically when creating components (dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949465/angular-2-inserting-capture-element-dynamically-when-creating-components-dynam)

Comment: @user2972309 Did the answer help you?